# Return search results matching multiple query tags?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) based on Laravel.

I have an html search field which query string is parsed with php.

Laravel returns database results based on the url `tag` parameter using MySQL `WHERE LIKE`.

It works with 1 tag, but how to return results matching multiple tags separated by commas or spaces?

#### HTML5 Search Input

```
<form action="/search">
  <input type="search" name="tags" multiple>
  <button type="submit">search</button>
</form>
```

#### Single tag search

`localhost/search?tags=galaxy`

#### Multiple tag search

commas 
`localhost/search?tags=galaxy%2C+stars%2C+universe`
spaces
`localhost/search?tags=galaxy+stars+universe`

This should return any tags matching in the database table's tags column.

The problem is that it sees the query as `galaxy AND stars AND universe` and not individual tags: `galaxy`, `stars`, `universe`.

#### Search Results

```
$query_string = $tags = '';

$query_string = getenv('QUERY_STRING');

// Return search results matching query string
return $query->where('tags', 'like', "%$tags%");
```

[$query](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/query) is part of OctoberCMS.

#### Example

[image: results]

#### Problem

[image: problem]

Comment: I don't get it: "any" or "all"? How the tags are stored in the db? What is `$query`? And what exactly is your question?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Right now if I type "galaxy, stars". It sees the query as "galaxy + stars" and not individual tags. I'll rephrase that. Tags are stored in a table 'Gallery, and column 'tags'. An image is in the column 'name'. I'm using OctoberCMS and it requires $query, as part of the Query Builder plugin. I'll update the question.

Comment: You can use the [explode() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string. Also note that `'%$tags%'` won't work as you expect. You should use double quotes: `"%$tags%"`. I can't help more - there's not enough info (tables, relations, ..).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel If I explode() the $tags into an array, how could I then have mysql search the column for matches in the $tags array? I've also updated the question with another image.

Answer (score 0):

Confusing,. Try logical OR to find value in table column may be it will help, if your finding it from webpages first fetch meta tags in function like google use keyword for search result

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that the $tags variable becomes "galaxy, stars, universe" and don't know how to use mysql to separate it into individual words to use OR.

Comment: You are searching in mysql database right? So make a separate column  in table where you will store keywords only then use search query select * from DB.table where keyword= $keyword

Comment: When searching multiple tags, the multiple keywords in the query become a single keyword variable $tags. All tags joined together. Now when searching the database, it tries to match the joined keyword and returns empty.